# How to NON clickable dates from last and next month days in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

In Fullcalendar, I want to NON CLICKABLE or unselect the days which out of the current month. 
For example, maybe these days are the last month days or next month days. Who can tell me how to make it to be  NON CLICKABLE or unselect? (When user click on those days noting happen)

I tried:

```
.fc-other-month  {visibility: hidden;}
```

But it just hide them ...

This is my code :

```
var d = new Date();

var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventSources: [{
        url: 'show_records.php',
        color: 'green',
    }],
    events: [{
            "title": "Capodanno",
            "start": d.getFullYear()+"-01-01"
        },{
            "title": "Epifania",
            "start": d.getFullYear()+"-01-06"
        },{
            "title": "Festa Liberazione",
            "start": d.getFullYear()+"-04-25"
        },{
            "title": "Festa Lavoratori",
            "start": d.getFullYear()+"-05-01"
        },{
            "title": "Festa Repubblicstarta",
            "start": d.getFullYear()+"-06-02"
        },{
            "title": "SS Pietro e Paulo",
            "start": d.getFullYear()+"-06-29"
        },{
            "title": "Ferragosto",
            "start": d.getFullYear()+"-08-15"
        },{
            "title": "Santi",
            "start": d.getFullYear()+"-11-01"
        },{
            "title": "Immacolata",
            "start": d.getFullYear()+"-12-08"
        },{
            "title": "Natale",
            "start": d.getFullYear()+"-12-25"
        },{
            "title": "S.Stefano",
            "start": d.getFullYear()+"-12-28"
    }],

    eventColor: 'red',
    // Header of calander  
    header: {
        left: 'prev',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'next',
    },
    defaultView: 'month',
    // Italian languge 
    lang: 'it',
    // Saiz 
    height: 600,
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        // Changing BG color
        $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
        //Create modal here
        $('#myModal').modal();
        // Show Date in SPAN
        $('#spnDate').html(date.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
        // Put Date value in a variable 
        $('#date').attr('value', date.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
    },
    editable: true,
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check that the day date you are clicking it's not on the current active month, you can achieve this by adding a simple validation to your callbacks:

```
var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'getView' );

return date.month() == view.intervalStart.month();
```

Example:

```
dayClick: function( date, jsEvent, view ) { 
      if date.month() !=  view.intervalStart.month() {
          //do nothing..
      }
}
```

Callbacks often have as arguments the date or event you are clicking and the view.

Info about views: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/View_Object/
Or: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/

Comment: I have tried several times but its not working , I wrote all my calendar code above can you test it in my code and let me know if its working ? I really appreciate .

Comment: I have a working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/34ytuj4x/

Also, check your console for posible errors.

Comment: Thanks ... With some changes its working exactly the way i wanted .

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of ugly but instead of setting their visibility to hidden, you could assign them a background color, then check if the element has that background color in your dayClick and do nothing.

Comment: Thanks , but it have a class name can i use that class to do it ? can you show me how it ll work in practical way ?